# Prove that there exists a $c$ such that $f(c-1/8)=f(c+1/8)$

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose that the function $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f(0)=f(1)$, prove that there exists a number $c$ such that $$f(c-\frac{1}{8})=f(c+\frac{1}{8})$$

I am not sure how to prove its existence, but what I did was to find the possible range that $c$ is inside:
$0\le c-\frac{1}{8} \le1$ and $0\le c+\frac{1}{8} \le1$, and solving both inequalities gives: $$\frac{1}{8}\le c\le\frac{7}{8}$$

So far I have learnt the Extreme Value Theorem, Rolle's Theorem, Mean Value Theorem, Fermat's Theorem.

Appreciate it if you can help me on what should I do!

Comment: You could look at $g:[1/8,7/8]\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto f(x-1/8) - f(x+1/8)$.

Comment: Note that if $f$ is only continuous, you won't be able to use most of those theorems you listed (the extreme value theorem is still fine), since they apply to differentiable functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g:[\frac{1}{8},\frac{7}{8}]\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$\displaystyle{g(x) = f(x+{\small{\frac{1}{8}}}) - f(x-{\small{\frac{1}{8}}})}$.

The goal is to show that $g(c) = 0$, for some $c$.

If $g(\frac{k}{8})=0$, for some $k \in \{1,3,5,7\}$, then let $c=\frac{k}{8}$, and we're done.

Suppose then that $g(\frac{1}{8}),g(\frac{3}{8}),g(\frac{5}{8}),g(\frac{7}{8})$ are all nonzero.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;&
g({\small{\frac{1}{8}}})+
g({\small{\frac{3}{8}}})+
g({\small{\frac{5}{8}}})+
g({\small{\frac{7}{8}}})
\\[4pt]
=\;\,&
\left(f({\small{\frac{2}{8}}}) - f(0)\right) + 
\left(f({\small{\frac{4}{8}}}) - f({\small{\frac{2}{8}}})\right) +
\left(f({\small{\frac{6}{8}}}) - f({\small{\frac{4}{8}}})\right) +
\left(f(1) - f({\small{\frac{6}{8}}})\right)
\\[4pt]
=\;\,&f(1) - f(0)\\[4pt]
=\;\,&0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Since $g(\frac{1}{8}),g(\frac{3}{8}),g(\frac{5}{8}),g(\frac{7}{8})$ sum to zero, and since they're all nonzero, it follows that at least one of them is positive, and least one is negative.

Since $f$ is continuous on $[\frac{1}{8},\frac{7}{8}]$, so is $g$.

Hence, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, we must have $g(c) = 0$, for some $c$.

This completes the proof.